# Flutter Android: One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version.

Fix this issue by adding the following to /Users/qqq/data/github/qqq/qqq/android/app/build.gradle:
android {
ndkVersion 21.3.6528147
...
}

But if I add `ndkVersion` and my file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    ndkVersion 21.3.6528147

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
...
```

I receive different error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/qqq/data/qqq/qqq/qqq/android/app/build.gradle' line: 61

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/qqq/data/github/qqq/qqq/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/qqq/data/github/qqq/qqq/android/app/build.gradle': 61: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 61, column 9.
     android {
             ^

  1 error
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to official doc(https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) latest ndk version is `25.0.8775105` just update to latest and error should be gone.

Solution for 2022:

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.0.8775105" <-- add this line
}
```

Solution for March 2023:

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
}
```

Comment: yeah, You are right! I forgot about `""` ;)

Comment: wish the error message included the quotes instead of giving the confidence that it's a simple fix to add without quotes.

Comment: has any problems bump this value for users? in my app has a lot of users with bad devices, using android 6, 9 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I managed to solve it, by setting default values ...MyProject\android\app\build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
   
    targetSdkVersion 33
    minSdkVersion 30
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
}
```

Add the above lines

Answer (score 0):

In your `android/app/build.gradle` file update your NDK version:

```
android {
  ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android/app/build.gradle add Latest ndkversion Current ndkversion '25.1.8937393'
android {
namespace ""
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using a flutter module in a native Android apk, you will receive this error:

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to ...\flutter_module\.android\Flutter\build.gradle:
```

As you can't edit this generated file, you'll have to change this file:

```
<flutter_dir>\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy
```

you can add this to local.properties:

```
static String ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
```