# can't import a simple rive animation in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, animation, flutter-animation, rive

I am really struggling to import a single Rive animation into my Flutter app, and it doesn't work! I really don't know what to do... Please help me!

Here is the Rive file I downloaded and added to my assets, and I got all the dependencies of Rive too:

https://rive.app/community/5103-10277-handshake/

so [image]

here is the my code:

[image]

I literally tried everything, but I don't know where the problem is. In step 9, I can't see any animation!

Here are the errors that I get with the phone emulator:

here are the error that i get with phone emulator :
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no i don't  get error on web with chrome . but i get error when i am with phone emulator .

Comment: i edited my question and added the photo of errors with phone emulator

Comment: try updating ndk version https://stackoverflow.com/q/73032815/10157127

Comment: Post your app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

add this line in app level build.gradle

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
}
```

The NDK version 25.1.8937393 can be install manually by going into
`android studio` -> `SDK manager` -> `SDK tools`.
Select the show package detail checkbox.

You will be able to see all the NDK versions available.

More details: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

If it's helpful to you, then accept the answer and don't forget to upvote.

Comment: thank you for your help . i have a question . where i should add this line actually i am new to flutter and i don't  know where i should add it?

Comment: you can add in app level build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

add this line in app level build.gradle

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
}
```